# Running large amount of long running background jobs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, digital-ocean

We're building a web-app where users will be uploading potentially large files that will need to be processed in the background.  The task involves calling 3rd-party APIs so each job can take several hours to complete.  We're using DelayedJob to run the background jobs.  With every user kicking off a background job, each of which will take a few hours to finish, that will add up to a lot of background jobs every quickly.  I am wondering what would be the best way to setup the deployment for this?  We're currently hosted on DigitalOcean.  I've kicked off 10 DelayedJob workers.  Each one (when ideal) takes up 157MB. When actively running it utilizes around 900 MB.  Our user-base right now is pretty small so it's not an issue but will be one soon.  So on a 4GB droplet, I can probably run like 2 or 3 workers at a time.  How should we approach this issue?  Should we be looking at using DigitalOcean's API to auto-spin cheap droplets on demand?  Should we subscribe to high-memory droplets on a monthly basis instead? If we go with auto-spinning droplets, should we stick with DigitalOcean or would Heroku make more sense?  Or is the entire approach wrong and should we be approaching it from an entire different direction?  Any help/advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are limited by memory on the number of workers that you can run on your DigitalOcean host.

If you are worried about scaling, I would focus on making the workers as efficient as possible. Have you done any benchmarking to understanding where the 900MB of memory is being allocated? I'm not sure what the nature of these jobs are, but you mentioned large files. Are you reading the contents of these files into memory, or are you streaming them? Are you using a database with SQL you can tune? Are you making many small API calls when you could be using a batch endpoint? Are you assigning intermediary variables that must then be garbage collected? Can you compress the files before you send them?

Look at the job structure itself. I've found that background jobs work best with many smaller jobs rather than one larger job. This allows execution to happen in parallel, and be more load balanced across all workers. You could even have a job that generates other jobs. If you need a job to orchestrate callbacks when a group of jobs finishes there is a DelayedJobGroup plugin at https://github.com/salsify/delayed_job_groups_plugin that allows you to invoke a final job only after the sibling jobs complete. I would aim for an execution time of a single job to be under 30 seconds. This is arbitrary but it illustrates what I mean by smaller jobs.

Some hosting providers like Amazon provide spot instances where you can pay a lower price on servers that do not have guaranteed availability. These pair well with the many fewer jobs approach I mentioned earlier.

Finally, Ruby might not be the right tool for the job. There are faster languages, and if you are limited by memory, or CPU, you might consider writing these jobs and their workers in another language like Javascript, Go or Rust. These can pair well with a Ruby stack, but offload computationally expensive subroutines to faster languages.

Finally, like many scaling issues, if you have more money than time, you can always throw more hardware at it. At least for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Ben.  I ended up going with a high memory droplet on DO and started up 50 workers on it.  My thought is that I can just rent out more servers as we scale.  Also, was incorrect on memory consumption. It's actually more like 250MB per active process.

Answer (score 0):

I thing memory and time is more problem for you. you have to use sidekiq gem for this process because it will consume less time and memory consumption for doing the same job,because it uses redis as database which is key value pair db.if the problem continues go with java script.